# Ruby on Rails simple dropdown does not retain value on a page refresh using cookies

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, cookies

I have this very simple dropdown that selects the currency I want my page to display in. However, whenever I change the currency and then refresh the page, the selected option changes back to USD (the default value). I attempted to use cookies, but it is not working.

Here is my HTML which is just a form that calls a method in my controller:

```
<%= form_tag "/cryptos/currency_selector" do %>  
            <%= select_tag(cookies[:currency_symbol], options_for_select([['USD'], ['JPY'], ['AUD'], ['EUR'], ['GBP'], ['CHF']], params[:currency_symbol]), :onchange => "this.form.submit();") %>
          <% end %>
```

Controller Code which just prints out cookie value for testing:

```
#handles currency conversion dropdown selector
def currency_selector
 puts cookies[:currency_symbol]
end
```

It's not even setting my cookie since I get an empty string in the terminal. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First the form on your page:

```
<%= form_tag "/cryptos/currency_selector" do %>  
    <%= select_tag(:currency_symbol, 
        options_for_select(
          ['USD', 'JPY', 'AUD', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'CHF'], cookies[:selected_currency]
        ), 
        onchange: "this.form.submit();") %>
<% end %>
```

And in your controller method to which `/cryptos/currency_selector` points to:

```
  def currency_selector
    cookies[:selected_currency] = params[:currency_symbol]

    redirect_back fallback_location: root_url
  end
```

Further improvements you might consider:

- Move the list of available currencies into a model or at least a constant.
- Give the `/cryptos/currency_selector` path a proper name in your `routes.rb` and use that name in your form instead of the hardcoded path.

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for the advice as well!